# Wallpaper going under bar

Tags: customization, appearance

I'm having wallpaper problems, the wallpaper is going under my toolbar and iconbar and whatnot and I'm not exactly sure what to do about it.

[image]

I've played around with the appearance settings but no dice. This isn't the most complex Ubuntu problem but I'm sure it still fits here.

Comment: It is supposed to be like that. Notice that I think that any other option (like for example filling black under the panel and launcher) will lead to a (much, IMHO) worst appearance. Especially with semi-transparent launcher and panel. Anyway, if you want that, simply add a border to your background...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The edges of the wallpaper will *always* be under the top panel and launcher. The background is drawn in a window which fills the screen, and is at the lowest level of the stack. The top panel and launcher are at one of the highest levels of the window stack, so will always appear on top of things, which are not full-screen application windows.

Answer (score 0):

By default,the colours of your launcher and panel mimic the colour of your desktop wallpaper.I am assuming you are asking how to change that.

If you don't already have it,install the **compiz settings manager** using

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

Once installed,use the dash to launch it.
Click on the category Desktop.
Click on Ubuntu Unity Plugin.
You will see an option called panel opacity.Try changing it to a higher value.You can can then click on laucher option and increase the laucher opacity as well.higher the opacity,less the colour will resemble that of the wallpaper.I hope this answers your question.
it could also be that the resolution of the wallpaper you are trying to use isn't right.To find the resolution that will work best for your monitor,check the resolution of your default ubuntu wallpapers(you can see that under appearances).